# When using input = Console.ReadLine(); it doesnt go to the next line of code, it simply loops when I put anything

Tags: c#

Quick note: I come from python and other easier to use programming languages.

I dont know why it doesnt go and continue to the next line, this is the steps I took, I firstly run the script in visual studio and it runs and then I can input text into the debug console, I type something and it repeats the line of input so I input again and it doesnt go onto the next line it just loops at  input = Console.ReadLine();, I even tried copying code from the internet that simply asks for input and prints it and it does the same thing, I think its something to do with visual studio maybe, This is a first so I apologize if I made a mistake, thank you for your help.

here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Printing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            string input;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number for the times table");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("number is: " + input);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce, or perhaps I haven't understood what happens on your side.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I simply want it to go on to the next line of code the for loop and print the number is:. it doesnt continue and just loops the writeline part of the code

Comment: could it be something to do with visual studio, I searched through the internet and I came up empty so I feel like visual sudio is misconfig or something, I also get this warning message but I dont think it should stop it from working: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

Comment: The code as written will (1) display a message, (2) wait for user to press return, (3) display what the user entered, and then it will (4) loop printing all the numbers from 1 to 10 (skipping 0) and finally (5) will wait for the user to press return again. Which part of that aren't you expecting?

Comment: It repeats 2, and doesn't go to 3.

Comment: `It repeats 2, and doesn't go to 3` Are you pressing <RETURN> after entering something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG This was very annoying and finally found a way of fixing this, for what ever reason the internal console does not work at all at least on my linux system, I found a post 4 years old mention changing the console to integratedTerminal and that fixed it, it works now, to change the console go to your launch.json file and change internalconsole too integratedTerminal.

very frustrating but now its done.

Answer (score 0):

Something may be wrong with your Visual Studio. I've run your code in my computer and it works perfectly fine, nothing loops. Is VS updated to the latest version? Check Visual Studio Installer. And what console are you using? Is it the default Windows CMD? My advice would be to reinstall VS if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I should of mentioned I'm on linux and the debug Console is where it prints the first message and let's me input, I will have to check it out more.

Comment: I'm not so sure about Visual Studio on Linux. Is it compatible or are you using something like Wine to run it? Check in what ways the Linux console might be to the Windows one. Hope you solve it.

Comment: It's native so it works out of the box, though setting up the Microsoft library's were a bit annoying but it runs the code so thats a step.